# Do we need axiom of choice to prove $A \subset B \subset A \Rightarrow A = B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Do we need axiom of choice to prove $A \subset B \subset A \Rightarrow A = B$ ?

The proof is trivial, define $C = B \backslash A$. If $A \neq B$ then $C$ is nonempty, so **pick any element $x$ of $C$**, then $x \in C \Rightarrow x \in B, x \not \in A$, but as $B \subset A$, thus $x \in A$, a contradiction.

Do we need actually need AoC to justify the bolded part ?

Comment: The definition of $C$ non-empty says that there exists some $x \in C$. So no, you don't need the AoC... The AoC is needed when you know that you can pick an element from each set, but you need to make infinitely many such choices/picks at the same time.

Comment: Can I just point out that there is nothing to prove because this statement is an axiom of set theory ?

Comment: It’s essentially the axiom of extensionality, but perhaps you’re being asked to prove the statement using the axiom of extensionality and the definition of subset.

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively, you don't need the Axiom of Choice to make a *single* choice. You need Choice when you have to make infinitely many choices at once (at least in general).

So no, you don't need Choice here. If a set is non-empty, then you can pick an arbitrary element in it.